# Unable to deploy Acumos Portal on local VM. |

Tags: acumos

Following the [Flow 1 steps](https://docs.acumos.org/en/latest/submodules/system-integration/docs/z2a/installation-guide.html)

the pods status for acumos:

```
kubectl get pods -A
```

Status of Pods

[image]

Logs for acumos-cds

[image]

Logs for acumos-docker

[image]

ubuntu16.04-64bit 32G RAM + 16Core CPU

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have reach your pull docker rate limit, so fix this issue first.